# Laravel: retrieving data from a select statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, var-dump

I Tried retrieving my data from `$result` via:

```
$result->pluck('request_time');
```

and

```
$result->request_time;
```

Both give me a non-object error, 
`var_dump` returns:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
  object(stdClass)[167]
  public 'id' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=38)
  public 'request_time' => string '2015-05-10 17:01:02' (length=19)
  public 'account_id' => int XXXXXXX
  public 'NOW()' => string '2015-05-14 02:03:12' (length=19)
```

How do I retrieve the data without using the `DB::table->pluck` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving you a non-object error because `$result` is an array.

Try `$result[0]->request_time;`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = DB::table('yourtable')->where('foo', 'bar')->first();
dd($result->request_time);
```